# Is it possible to get precise user location in chrome if user logged in via google account?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, geolocation

If user uses desktop PC connected via ethernet and logged in using google account (in chrome) he will see their device location (for same account) on maps.google.com, but if i request location via JS (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ...) it will show different location (i suppose it will be internet provider location). How can I get precise location using google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#requests) returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect. This document describes the protocol used to send this data to the server and to return a response to the client.

Communication is done over HTTPS using POST. Both request and response are formatted as JSON, and the content type of both is application/json.

HTTP request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

A successful geolocation request will return a JSON-formatted response defining a location and radius.

- location: The user’s estimated latitude and longitude, in degrees. Contains one lat and one lng subfield.
- accuracy: The accuracy of the estimated location, in meters. This represents the radius of a circle around the given location.

> { "location": { "lat": 51.0, "lng": -0.1 }, "accuracy": 1200.4 }

If your Geolocation response shows a very high value in the accuracy field, the service may be geolocating based on the request IP, instead of WiFi points or cell towers. This can happen if no cell towers or access points are valid or recognized.